# Eignevalue of matrix by inspection?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How to find by inspection the eigen value and the geometric multiplicity of a 2 X 2 matrix?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the characteristic equation is

$\lambda^2 - trace(A) \lambda + det(A) = 0$
and you can plug that into the binomial theorem.

Comment: @amd Thanks....

Answer (score 3):

It might be helpful to notice that if $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ are the eigenvalues of a $2\times2$ matrix $A$, then

$$\text{trace}(A) = \lambda_1+\lambda_2$$
$$\det(A) = \lambda_1\lambda_2$$

This might not immediately provide the values of $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ upon inspection of these two equations, but these equations aren't particularly difficult to solve.